# Using existing Setup Objects in Test Class - Mixed DML Operation error

Tags: apex, customsetting

I'm writing a Test Class in order to test some code which automatically completes CaseMilestones when certain changes are made to a Case.

My code checks that the Case which has been changed has a Record Type Id that's included in my Custom Setting. In my Test Class, I need to create the Custom Setting and also create the CaseMilestones, Account, Entitlement, Opportunity etc. which the Case that I update in the Test Class will be related to.

As soon as the test get's to the line `insert msList;` it causes the test to fail, with the error stating that the combination of the Custom Setting & Milestone caused the Mixed DML Operation error.

I've found plenty for explanations of this error & solutions but in every example that I've seen, the assumption is that the purpose of the code is to Insert the Setup Object which means that a @future class can be written & referenced in the Test Class, see the [Salesforce documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm), for example.

My Custom Setting already exists and doesn't need to be inserted again in Production so I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

```
@isTest
private class completeCaseMilestone_Test {

    static testMethod void testCaseMilestone(){

        WEID__c[] csList = new WEID__c[]{};
            WEID__c cs = New WEID__c();

        cs.Name = 'WE Application';
        cs.WECaseId__c = '012700000005x2r';
        csList.add(cs);

        insert csList;
        system.debug('csList contains ' + csList);

        List <MilestoneType> msList = new List <MilestoneType>();

        MilestoneType m1 = new MilestoneType();
        m1.Name = 'Case Accepted';
        msList.add(m1);

        MilestoneType m2 = new MilestoneType();
        m2.Name = 'Create & CSDM Approve Account';
        msList.add(m2);

        insert msList;

        User u = new User();

        u.FirstName = 'A';
        u.LastName = 'S';
        u.Email = 'test@test.com';
        u.Username = 'astest@test.com';
        u.Alias = 'astest';
        u.ProfileId = p1.Id;
        u.TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Denver';
        u.LocaleSidKey      = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey  = 'UTF-8';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

        insert u;
        system.debug('u contains ' + u);

        // create Account, Entitlement, Opportunity etc.

        Case c = new Case();

        c.OwnerId = u.id;
        c.Status = 'Application Submitted';
        c.Subject = 'Test Submit Application';

        c.RecordTypeId = '012700000005x2r';
        c.Subject = 'New Application';
        c.EntitlementId = ent.Id;
        c.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        c.AccountId = a.Id;

        insert c;

        List<Case> cToUpdate = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Status FROM Case
                                WHERE Subject = 'Test Submit Application'];

        system.debug('cToUpdate contains ' + cToUpdate);

        for (Case case1 : cToUpdate){
            c.OwnerId = u.id;
        }
        update cToUpdate;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when you insert data in both regular objects and setup objects in the same transaction. Best way to overcome this error is to insert a user and other setup objects in test class and use `System.runAs()`. Check the link below,

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs

**UPDATE** - Insertion of user cannot be done with other transactions. Insert user first and then put all other code inside

```
System.runas(u){
    //test coverage code here.
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
@isTest
private class completeCaseMilestone_Test {

    static testMethod void testCaseMilestone(){

        Profile p1 = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator - Test'];

        // create User
        User u = new User();

        u.FirstName = 'A';
        u.LastName = 'S';
        u.Email = 'test@test.com';
        u.Username = 'astest@test.com';
        u.Alias = 'astest';
        u.ProfileId = p1.Id;
        u.TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Denver';
        u.LocaleSidKey      = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey  = 'UTF-8';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

        insert u;
        system.debug('u contains ' + u);

        System.runas(u){

            // create non-setup records & run tests here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so to clarify, I create the Custom Setting and the User, then runAs and create the remaining records and do the testing?

Comment: I have updated answer. Please check

Comment: I'm still not completely sure how this solution will work but I'll have a go and let you know whether it works.

Comment: system.runas(u) will simulate execution as the different user u